# Выводится System.String[]

Tags: c#

Я студент и у меня есть задача - вывести матрицу (многомерный массив) в консоль так, чтобы это было приемлемо для чтения. Для этого я написал функцию, которая переводит тот самый многомерный массив:

```
static string[] ArrayToString(double[,] L)
    {
        int n = L.GetLength(0),m = L.GetLength(1);
        string[] S = new string[n]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            string s = "";
            for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                s += L[i, j].ToString();
                s += " ";
            }
            S[i] = s;
        }
        return S;
    }
```

**На что я получаю ответ в консоль в виде: System.String[]**
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть дело?

*если Вам требуется код для примера, то вот он:

```
private static void exercise_1_0()
    {
        int n = 2, m = 2;
        var A = new double[n, m];
        double ans = 0;
        Console.WriteLine($"Введите {n} строк {m} столбца");

        for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        for (var j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            A[i, j] = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(A));
    }
```

Comment: Выводится где и как? В показанном вами коде нет ничего, что совершало бы какой-нибудь вывод в консоль

Comment: Ну и логика подсказывает, что в консоль обычно выводят строки, а не массивы строк. А чтобы вывести массив строк в консоль, нужно каким-то образом преобразовать его в строку желаемого вами вида — чего вы, видимо, не сделали. Ну или хотя бы пройтись циклом по этому массиву, что ли?

Comment: вероятнее всего ты выводишь этот массив без индексов, вот он тебе и возвращает объект. Покажи код вывода, тогда понятнее будет

Comment: Я добавил код вывода.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(ArrayToString(A));` — ну да, не сделали. Сделайте тогда хотя бы `Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", ArrayToString(A)));` например?

Comment: @andreymal спасибо. Вы можете разместить это как ответ чтобы я отметил это верным решением. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в аргументы `Console.WriteLine()` поступает массив, а т.к у `Console.WriteLine()` нет перегрузки для массивов, то он считает массив как `object` и выводит его как `arg.GetType().ToString()`
Так, вам необходимо выводить отдельно каждую цифру или же использовать `string.Join(' ', [одномерный массив]matrixD1)` как аргумент в `Console.WriteLine()`
Вот рабочий код:

```
double[,] matrix = new double[,]
{
    { 13.3, 0.3, 3.2, 0.3 },
    { 0, 0.3, 3.2, 22 },
    { 93, 1, 3.2, 23 },
    { 2.8, 44.3, 27.1, 71 },
    { 8, 0, 2.1, 32 },
};

int l0 = matrix.GetLength(0),
    l1 = matrix.GetLength(1);

for (int d0 = 0; d0 < l0; d0++)
{
    for (int d1 = 0; d1 < l1; d1++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[d0, d1]);
        Console.Write(' ');
    }
    Console.Write('\n');
}
```

Выведет:

```
13,3 0,3 3,2 0,3
0 0,3 3,2 22
93 1 3,2 23
2,8 44,3 27,1 71
8 0 2,1 32
```

Но для читабельности я бы посоветовал найти самый длинный элемент и добавлять к остальным недостающее количество пробелов (Может сломаться при не monostyle шрифте)

Код:

```
double[,] matrix = new double[,]
{
    { 13.3, 0.3, 3.2, 0.3 },
    { 0, 0.3, 3.2, 22 },
    { 93, 1, 3.2, 23 },
    { 2.8, 44.3, 27.1, 71 },
    { 8, 0, 2.1, 32 },
};

int l0 = matrix.GetLength(0),
    l1 = matrix.GetLength(1);

int biggestElementSize = 1;

for (int d0 = 0; d0 < l0; d0++)
{
    for (int d1 = 0; d1 < l1; d1++)
    {
        int elementSize = matrix[d0, d1].ToString().Length;
        if (elementSize > biggestElementSize)
            biggestElementSize = elementSize;
    }
}

for (int d0 = 0; d0 < l0; d0++)
{
    for (int d1 = 0; d1 < l1; d1++)
    {
        Console.Write(matrix[d0, d1].ToString().PadRight(biggestElementSize, ' '));
        Console.Write("  ");
    }
    Console.Write('\n');
}
```

Выведет:

```
13,3  0,3   3,2   0,3
0     0,3   3,2   22
93    1     3,2   23
2,8   44,3  27,1  71
8     0     2,1   32
```

Comment: 1) `int biggestElementSize = matrix.Cast<double>().Select(x => x.ToString().Length).Max();` :) 2) `Console.Write('\n');`? `Console.WriteLine();`! 3) `Console.Write("  ");`? `.PadRight(biggestElementSize + 2, ' ')`!