# Ни одна из перегрузок метода "Write" не принимает 0 аргументов

Tags: c#

Люди помогите, новичок в c# и появилась ошибка, которую я не могу решить "Ни одна из перегрузок метода "Write" не принимает 0 аргументов."

```
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    Console.Write();
    HelloWorld.WriteSentence();
    }
    
  public static void WriteSentence() {
    string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
    Console.WriteLine(words);
    }
}
```

Вот дополнение кода

```
    string sentence = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
    foreach(string word in words){
      Console.WriteLine(word);
    }
```

Comment: Что вы вообще пытались сделать строкой `Console.Write();` ?

Comment: Ну да, WriteLine хотя бы строку переводит и имеет смысл и без аргументов поэтому. А просто Write смысла не имеет.

Comment: Он нужен для ввода текста

Comment: Write не имеет никакого отношения к вводу

Comment: Смотрите, а как тогда решить проблему,я ввожу предложение, а на выходе получаю System.String[]

Comment: Почему это проблема? Вы хотите получить что-то другое?

Comment: Я хочу получить список слов, если делать через foreach, то тоже самое получаю

Comment: Ну значит преобразовывайте массив в такую строку, которую вы желаете видеть. Про вывод массива строк здесь уже был вопрос: [Выводится System.String\[\]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1463323)

Comment: А про foreach непонятно, в показанном вами коде нету никакого foreach. Ну и в любом случае это всё никак не относится к бессмысленности строки `Console.Write();`

Comment: Это я понял, спасибо

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, words));` или циклом